# What is it about the sin of a constant that changes the derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Capitols are constants:
$$y(t) = Vt \sin(A)   - 4.9  t^2$$

I would expect the derivative to be:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = V  \sin(A) - 9.8  t$$

However, I'm told this is incorrect. Does anyone know why?

Comment: When in doubt of a simple computation, try wolframalpha first. For instance,

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate+Ax+%5Csin%28B%29+-4.9+x%5E2

Comment: Assuming $A$ and $V$ are just constants, what you've done is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Who said that was wrong? You're correct. Assuming $V$ and $A$ aren't functions of $t$

Comment: They're not functions of t, and it was a physics assignment.

Comment: What did they say the answer was?